# Can you disconnect a command after it has been set with Mvvm-Light on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

I'm using Mvvm-Light to create a binding to a `UIButton` with the `SetCommand` extension. I can just call it in `ViewDidLoad(...)` but I want to connect it in `ViewWillAppear(...)` and disconnect it in `ViewWillDisappear(...)` like I do with the rest of my bindings. So all bindings are only active when the view is visible. If I do it this way currently then `SetCommand` is called every time I navigate back to the view and the `RelayCommand` is fired multiple times, once for every call to to `SetCommand`.

Is this possible? And if not, then why not?

Comment: Hi, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do you want to  disconnect a command?

If a UIViewController has disappeared, all of his controls can't be touched and seen. So the command will only fire when it appears again, I think this has already fitted your request.

If you do want to remove this command in the event `ViewWillDisappear()` you can use:

```
button.RemoveTarget(null, null, UIControlEvent.AllEvents);
```

This will remove all the events the button has. As you say when you `SetCommand()` again in the event `ViewWillAppear()` the `RelayCommand` will only be called once.

Comment: Just to further expand on my requirements, it may be the case that you don't care if the view controller has disappeared, but in a cell re-use scenario it becomes a necessity to unsubscribe and resubscribe events. I don't understand why this isn't available.